# React/Redux - getting json data from fetch request gives undefined for property in response body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I have a fetch request where I am getting a data object that has an items array in it.

```
export const getItems = (searchString: string, limit?: string, offset?: string) => (dispatch: ThunkDispatch) => {
  const searchUrl = `https://search.items.ai/search?q=${searchString || ''}&offset=${offset ? offset : '0'}&limit=${limit ? limit : '10'}`
  return dispatch(
    asyncRequest(
      fetch(searchUrl, {
        method: 'GET',
      }), SEARCH_ITEMS)
  )
}
```

I have a reducer that looks like this:

```
const initialState = Map({
  fetchedItems: Map()
})

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SEARCH_ITEMS.SUCCESS:
      console.log('body', action.body)
      return state.setIn([AUTOSUGGEST_ITEMS], fromJS(action.body.data.items))
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

In my component I am mapping state to props like this:

```
export default connect(
  (state) => {
    const searchType = AUTOSUGGEST_ITEMS
    const searchResults = state.getIn(['searchReducer', searchType])
    return ({
      searchResults: isNotEmpty(searchResults) ? searchResults.valueSeq().sort(sortByName).toJS() : [],
      searchType: searchType,
    })
  },
  {
    push,
    clearSearchSuggestions,
    getItems
  }
)(AutoSuggestWrapper)
```

I can see that the fetch request it successful when I log the json body of the response. I get an object that looks like this:

```
body {"data":{"items":[{}]}}
```

But, when I try to set the state `state.setIn([AUTOSUGGEST_ITEMS], fromJS(action.body.data.items))`I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined at reducer
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
```

I don't have much experience with redux and none with and none with immutable library, so I am not sure if what is wrong here?

Comment: try console logging action.body.data and check whether it is defined or not.

Comment: I get undefined for data, why is it so, when I can see it in the body?

Comment: can you share codesandbox link or something else where I can reproduce this error

Comment: are you sure the path in the state is correct? I can't say for sure without complete code, but I see the reducer saves to `[AUTOSUGGEST_ITEMS]` while the get in the component is `['searchReducer', AUTOSUGGEST_ITEMS]`. 
And `.valueSeq().sort(sortByName).toJS()` in `connect` is _terrible_! It sorts and transforms the data to a new object on every run of the selector! That guarantees to always result in a change. ImmutableJS is fast when used correctly, but these things need to be cached or saved to the state in the correct form.